# This question is for sequences, how would I go about solving this?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Find a general term (expressed as a function of the variable $n$) for the following sequence:

$$\{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4,\dots\}=\left\{\frac{4}{8}, \frac{16}{64}, \frac{64}{512}, \frac{256}{4096},\;\ldots\right\}.$$

Comment: If [this account](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/214166/guest-anon) also belongs to you, you can merge the two accounts using the instructions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8403/announcement-new-user-merge-policy-tool). (I am just guessing, based on the same username.)

Answer (score 4):

You essentially have the sequence $$\{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4,\ldots\} = \left\{\frac 12,\;\frac 14, \;\frac 18,\; \frac{1}{16},\; \ldots\right\}. $$ So the $n^{\large \text{th}}$ term in the sequence is given by $$a_n = \frac 1{2^n} = \left(\frac 12\right)^n.$$

Comment: wow thanks can't believe I missed that

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's helpful to treat the numerator and the denominator as separate sequences.$$\{4,16,64...\}\implies a_n=4^n \\\{8,64,512..\}\implies b_n=8^n$$  So the nth term of the original sequence is $c_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{4^n}{8^n}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$

I thought this might be useful  to add for situations that are difficult to spot.